# Vim function to display the number of remaining 'Ctrl+I' style jumps (and display output in the statusline)?

Tags: vim

I use `CTRL`+`O` and `CTRL`+`I` a lot to traverse the jumplist. Sometimes I
find that I forget whether I'm at the end of the jumplist and I press
`CTRL`+`I` expecting to go forwards in the jumplist, and instead I go nowhere,
hit it again, go nowhere, and only then conclude I'm already at the end of the
jumplist.  I find this mentally jarring and would like to encode the
information in my status line. So what I'm looking for is a function to tell me
one of two things:

1. In the case that I'm not already at the end of the jumplist, as in the first
   example below, I want the jump number associated with the last line (in that
   example '1')
2. In the case that I am at the end of the jumplist, as in the second example
   below, I want to return zero.

Example 1: my jumplist from when I was composing this question and I've jumped
back with `CTRL`+`O`:

```
 jump line  col file/text
   2     1    0 This is a small thing but it irritates me...
>  0     4   37 find that I forget whether I'm at the end of the jumplist and I press
   1     5   78 `CTRL`+`I` expecting to go forwards in the jumplist, and instead I go nowhere,
```

Example 2: how it looks when I've hit `CTRL`+`I` until I'm all the way to the end
of the jumplist:

```
 jump line  col file/text
   3     1    0 This is a small thing but it irritates me...
   2     4   37 find that I forget whether I'm at the end of the jumplist and I press
   1     5   78 `CTRL`+`I` expecting to go forwards in the jumplist, and instead I go nowhere,
>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `getjumplist()`. It returns a list whose first item is the jumplist, and the second one is the most recently used jump position. (See `:help getjumplist()`.) So you can compare the length of its first item and the second item. You can put a function like the following in your vimrc.

```
function! RemainingJumps()
  let [l:jumplist, l:pos] = getjumplist()
  return max([0, len(l:jumplist) - l:pos - 1])
endfunction
```

As for printing its result in the statusline, I guess it depends on how you configure your statusline: whether you use lightline.vim, vim-airline, or the vanilla statusline.

Oh I found out your vimrc constructs the statusline from scratch without a plugin! In this case you can add something like

```
set statusline+=\ %{RemainingJumps().'\ Jumps'}
```